# How To Reference Group Layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to create and if/else loop for three sublayers in a group layer. If it's the group layer (0) then the sublayers have certain labels. If it's group layer (4) then the sublayers have other labels, etc.

Here's what I've tried. I've also tried arrays [0] instead of '0'.

```
                   if(identifyParams.layerIds === '0'){

                          if(layerName === '10% Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '24 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "10% Damage Risk";
                               }

                          else if(layerName === '90%  Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '24 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "90% Damage Risk";
                               }

                          else if(layerName === 'Overall Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '24 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "Possible Damage";
                               }

                          }

                    if(identifyParams.layerIds === '4'){

                          if(layerName === '10% Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '48 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "10% Damage Risk";
                               }

                          else if(layerName === '90% Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '48 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "90%  Damage Risk";
                               }

                          else if(layerName === 'Overall Damage Risk'){
                               layerLabel = '48 Hour Forecast';
                               label = "Possible Damage";
                               }

                          }
```

I've also tried, but it didn't work.

```
   if(layerName === '24 Hour Forecast')
```

Comment: Instead of using group layers, I'm just referencing the layer ID. I still can't get it to work. When I click this layer, I get "no information available" in the popup. If I change it back to layer name, it works. 
 
     if(layerID === '2')